# How to Change Color of Joined Object without Manually Clicking Each Specific Object?

Tags: edit-mode, vertices, faces, color

So I have my character face and this course said to join the eyebrows and mouth + teeth to make shape keys easier for animation.

However, when I want to duplicate my character and change the skin color, it changes the eyebrows + teeth and tongue to the same skin color because those objects are all joined to the face.

Since I joined the objects, they don't appear separately in the right side bar anymore, and only show the entire body. So I have to manually go into edit more and click the eyebrows then change the color, then go to the teeth then the tongue etc.

So example is my mouth below. The outer part is the skin, but those intruding pieces is the mouth with teeth top/bottom and tongue in middle.

[image]

This is what it looks like when colored

[image]

So the only way I can change the skin color of "blue" when I duplicate my character is to select all the faces using A then change.

Only solution to avoid the teeth/mouth/eyebrow/eyes to not change is if I manually click each face every time which gets time consuming because theres so many faces.

Is there a different view where I can just click on the face/body to change the skin color without affecting the joined objects?

Answer (score 0):

If your character's teeth are arent connected to the head, you can use the key L while hovering over the mesh you want to select (instead of individually setting selecting the faces.
additionally another way to do this easily is to set up separate material slots for the colors[image]

This way if you want to change the red part into green for example, you can change it without affecting the blue part